# help in understanding pullback formula

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, pullback

My differential geometry course introduced the following formula for computing pullbacks by a $k$-form:

$f^{*}\alpha = \sum (f \circ a_J) df^{j_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge df^{j_{l}}$.

My instructor computed the pullback $f^{*} \alpha$, where $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1^2 + x_2^2, \sin(x_3))$, and $\alpha = y_1^2 dy_1 + y_2^3 dy_2$. He then got as the answer before simplification:

$f^{*}\alpha = (x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2 d(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + (\sin(x_3))^3 d(\sin(x_3))$.

Could someone please explain how he obtained this result from the general formula written above? I am slightly confused on the indices.

Thanks.

Comment: That should be $f^{*}\alpha = (x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2 d(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + (\sin(x_3))^3 d(\sin(x_3))$.  You basically just substitute $x_1^2 + x_2^2$ for $y_1$ and $\sin(x_3)$ for $y_2$: that's what the composition $f \circ \alpha_J$ is.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the missing exponent in the question. So, when you say composition of $f \circ a_J$, do we take this composition component-wise? since $f = (f_1, f_2)$ from above?

Comment: Actually, I guess it should be $\alpha_J \circ f$, not $f \circ \alpha_J$.  In your example, $f$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and each $\alpha_J$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.  But yes, componentwise is right.  Take a look at p. 137 of Lee's *Introduction To Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: Thomas, if you're just learning the differential forms game, it might help you to watch some of my [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). Start with Day 24 of MATH 3510 at the very bottom and then proceed to Days 25, 26, ...., as needed above.